# Pyspark UDF with list of dense vectors returning error

Tags: pyspark

I'm trying to create a udf that takes as input a column where each row is a list of dense vectors. I want to return the column itself. (Actually, I want to perform operations on that column, but I'm not even able to return the column itself). Not sure what I'm missing:

```
def random_udf(col1):
   return col1


convertUDF = udf(lambda col1: random_udf(col1), ArrayType(VectorUDT()))

df=df.withColumn("score", convertUDF("DESCRIPTION"))

df.show()
```

Error I'm getting:

```
_pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object
```

Thank you!

Comment: So what kind of operations do you want to do to that column? Are the length of the vector the same in the array?

Comment: No, operations at this stage. Just return itself.

Comment: Then what is the origin data type of the `score` column? Could you provide some sample data?

Comment: A row of the column would look like ```[vector.dense([1.0, 2.0]), vector.dense([1.0, 2.0])]```